# Getting error when putting VARCHAR data and searching INT value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Below is my query and error. When I am putting VARCHAR variable and pass in INT value then I am getting error.

Query:

```
    declare @vid VARCHAR(MAX)
    set @vid= ('3,5,7')

    Select (Stuff((Select ', ' + VehicleClassName 
    From VehicleClass_Master  
    where VehicleClassId  in (@VID) FOR XML PATH('')),1,2,''))
```

Error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>       Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3,5,7' to data type int.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/q/337704/1048425

Answer (score 1):

Your variable @vid is a varchar containing non-numeric characters (,); also it is not a "list" it is simply a string containing a single value that happens to have numbers and commas in it.

To acheive what you want, create @vid as a table variable with a single INT column, then insert each value as a separate row - `INSERT @vid_table(vid) VALUES (3),(5),(7);`

Finally change your `IN (@VID)` to `IN (SELECT VID FROM @vid_table)`

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @vid VARCHAR(MAX),@query varchar(max)
set @vid= ('3,5,7')
SET @query = 'Select (Stuff((Select '', '' + VehicleClassName From VehicleClass_Master  where VehicleClassId  in (' + @vid + ') FOR XML PATH('''')),1,2,''''))'
EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Or you could do it as dynamic SQL :)